# Android postScale not scaling as expected

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling

I have got a load of Bitmaps that I now am trying to scale depending on the screen size, The way I do this is by dividing the current device screen size with my test phones size because all images were made according to that screensize.

The function I use is below

```
public Bitmap resizeBitmap(Bitmap b){
      int width = b.getWidth();
      int height = b.getHeight();
      Matrix max = new Matrix();

      max.postScale(Vars.screenWidthMulti, Vars.screenHeightMulti);
      Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, width, height, max, false);
      return resizedBitmap;
}
```

screenWidthMulti and screenHeightMulti is gotten by dividing the current screensize with an float value same as my test devices screen. Now that part works fine.
If I use a device with screensize of 1024/552 and my device is 960/540 the scaling values I get is 1.06666667 for width and 1.02222223 for height which is fine.

Now The problem is that when I postScale it with those values it doesnt scale them as I'd expect. For example an background image that is same size as my test device is put in then the size of the Bitmap outputted is 683 by 368 which doesn't make any sense to me what so ever! I have tried with preScale and setScale too but that doesnt change for the better either.

Is there any other way that might be easier and actually works or is it just me not understanding this?

EDIT: I tried putting in a value of 2f in the setScale and it turned out quite strange, 540*2 turned out 720 which I cannot get my head around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figued this out by multiplying the scaling factor by 1.5 , weird but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You just created the matrix, so you don't need a post or preScale, just use setScale:

```
Matrix max = new Matrix();
max.setScale(Vars.screenWidthMulti, Vars.screenHeightMulti);
```

Comment: I tested it right now and it didn't change even the slightest. Thanks for trying to help though.